# How To Optimize React compiled.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, react-redux

[image]

My node_modules fairly huge: ~5MB . After gzipping, it gives 2.5MB but this still takes ~5-8secs whenever my web app is requested. This feels very slow, even though my source code only takes about 500kb.

How can I optimize this?

Comment: You should try and remove and pacakges that you are not using

Comment: how much of jquery and lodash you are actually using, I normally manually export the exact function I use that saves me a lot of space

Comment: A lot of the libraries that you might be using could be very trivial to avoid or replaced with a lightweight one. A few examples are lodash and jquery which contribute a lot to your bundle size

Comment: this is really weird; import _ from 'lodash'; is the only part i use from lodash. Why is it bringing the whole lodash library in?

Comment: @user1955934 you should use a packer like webpack that builds a single file with all your dependencies. Webpack supports minification, which makes the Javascript super small by removing unneeded spaces, reducing variable names, etc.
Like others said, you can manually import the lodash modules you need. If you require the whole thing, the whole lodash library is loaded and thus bundled with your code.

Comment: ok i changed all the lodash imports to something like import orderBy from 'lodash/orderBy';
but webpack bundle analyzer still sees the same size from lodash....